# Connect-PnPOnline Invalid URI when running from script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to automate the creation of items on a SharePoint list which is almost working but I've hit a wall where if I run the following two lines in PowerShell, it connects fine and further commands work correctly. If I have the same commands in a PowerShell script I get the error "Connect-PnPOnline : Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid."

```
$SiteURL = 'https://oursite.sharepoint.com/sites/othersite'
Connect-PnPOnline –Url $SiteURL –UseWebLogin
```

All my searching has only come up with adding "write-output $SiteURL" after connect but didn't make a difference and I don't think is the issue.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Edit - For those that find this, the issue ended up being that the code was copied and pasted into Visual Studio Code. The hyphen in front of URL turned out not to be a hyphen but an en dash. When pasted into PowerShell it converted automatically but for reasons I have yet to determine the script didn't, thus gave the error. Swapped the dash for the correct hyphen character and it worked!

Comment: Is `$SiteUrl` in your script hardcoded like in your example? Without showing the code in that script, it is quite impossible to answer..

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've edited my post as I found the issue.

Comment: Well spotted! These things happen frequently and are very easy to overlook.

Comment: Thank you very much - had the same problem. Unfortunately there's no upvotable answer. You might consider answering your own question with the solution so that people can upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a xml file which contains list of site collections. I am reading the xml file from power shell and trying to connect each URL by Connect-PnpOnline method. I was getting the same error Invalid URI. I had placed url inside the single quotes in the xml file. I resolved it by removing the single quotes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).